# Is it possible to deactivate ls-remote check in NPM?

Tags: git, npm, npm-install, artifactory, git-ls-remote

I trying to use `npm` packages behind artifactory system and corporative proxy settings,

every time that I try to load the `vue-select` package (but not limited to it), all packages are downloaded from artifactory repository, but executes the following command

```
ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/sagalbot/vue-select.git
```

which is blocked by the proxy rules.

I added the following settings to the `npmrc` file

```
npm config set registry http://artifactory.<url>/
npm set strict-ssl false
```

I'm not sure if this is an expected behaviour, but is it possible to change or deactivate it?